# Laravel count morph many group by relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-8

I have like this model:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
    }

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Image::class, 'imageable');
    }

    public function views()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(View::class, 'viewable'); 
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

With this query I'll get posts:

```
$posts = Post::query()
            ->with([
                'category',
                'images',
            ])
            ->withCount([
                'views'
            ])
            ->get();
```

**Question:**

How I can sum post views and group by category to get total views on each category?

I can get needed result using raw SQL query like this:

```
SELECT `categories`.`title` AS `category`,
    COUNT(`views`.`viewable_id`) AS `totalViews`
FROM `posts`
LEFT JOIN `categories`
    ON `categories`.`id` = `posts`.`category_id`
LEFT JOIN `views`
    ON `views`.`viewable_id` = `posts`.`id`
WHERE `views`.`viewable_type` = "App\\Models\\Post"
GROUP BY `categories`.`id`
```

But how I can generate like this sql query using laravel eloquent and get result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce on the `$posts` collection. Something similar to:

```
$categoriesCounts = $posts->reduce(static function(array $carry, Post $post) {

    $carry[$post->category_id] = ($carry[$post->category_id] ?? 0) + $post->views_count;

    return $carry;
}, []);
```

The resulted array will look like:

```
array(3) {
  [1] => int(4)
  [5] => int(20)
  [6] => int(10)
}
```

Comment: But how I can get like this result only using eloquent (sql) without php in my case? I've updated my question and you can see my raw query.